# Что значит каждая из элементов строки: $this->description = $description; Подробнее ниже

Tags: php, php7

Код самой программы:

```
<?php 

class Task {

  protected $description; //защищённая перем. класса

  protected $completed=true; //защищённая булевая перем. класса

  public function __construct($description) //общедоступная ф-ия
  {
      $this->description = $description; 
  }
}

$task = new Task('Go to the store'); //объявление объекта класса

var_dump($task); //вывести на экран перемен. $task в соответствии с ф-ей 
var_dump

require 'class.view.php';

?>
```

Файл class.view.php представляет собой пустой html-каркас. Все мои поиски дали понять что код **$this->description = $description;** неотъемлемая часть конструктора в php, но я не получил внятного ответа на то:

- $thsis - что это за перем. и что оно делает в этой конструкции?
- description - то ли это перем. класса, то ли это параметр перем. класса, то ли это св-во объекта - тоже не понятно, какую роль description выполняет в этой конструкции?
- И последнее $description - это перем., как она связана с этим description?

Comment: Без доки не обойтись. Нашел, что по-проще https://puzzleweb.ru/php/24_oop.php

Comment: Получается:
Чтобы получить доступ к членам класса внутри класса, необходимо использовать указатель $this;

Comment: Не класса, а созданного объекта класса. Сам класс это как бы описание/спецификация для создания объектов

Comment: вы хоть чуть чуть пытались прочитать документацию по ООП в ПХП ?

Comment: А значение описание __construct() присваивается переменной класса description?

Comment: нет, это конструктор для создания объектов класса. И в данном случае он имеет один аргумент ($description), который инициализирует значение поля объекта $this->description (не путайте их, это разные переменные), а $this служит для того, чтобы получить доступ к этому полю в php. Почитайте документацию внимательно. Или скачайте самую тонкую книжку по php )

Comment: Alexander Chernin - спасибо.